# How to download a file in ASP.NET Core API

Tags: asp.net-core, download

I am consuming third party API which is returning a `.pdf` file in
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQRHr.png) ([here is full content of pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If2nz.png)) format.

And I am trying to download this file like this:

```
byte[] fileBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response.Content);
return File(fileBytes, "application/force-download", "Test.pdf");
```

but problem is that for some files, it works as expected, but not for all files, unexpected results are as follows

[image: Downloaded pdf1]

[image: Downloaded pdf2]

All helpful answer(s) will be appreciated.

Comment: Where does `response.Content` come from? Show the code, since that may contain the problem.

Comment: Are you sure they are all encoded the same way? I would suggest using different encoding on those files and see if it works.

Comment: @PoulBak that is API response which is working fine 
var response = client.Get(request);
I don't think there can be any problem.

Comment: @vsarunov yes, I tried other encoding methods but doesn't get solution

Comment: If it is a HTTP response, maybe you firstly need to `response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()` and then use the value. Have you tried this?

Comment: @vsarunov this is Rest Request
"new RestRequest(path, Method.GET, DataFormat.Json)"